# Limit or disappearing Sharepoint Validation Settings Formulas

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have this formula to validate dropdowns and empty textfields. I get no error message when I save it but when I come back to edit this formula, it is nowhere to be found!

I know there is a limit with the length that is why you will see a lot of abbreviation matching the title labels but a disappearing formula???

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK([Resolved Exception])=TRUE,Resolved<>"Yes"),FALSE,
IF(AND(ISBLANK([Ethics Exception])=TRUE,Ethics<>"Yes"),FALSE,
IF(AND(ISBLANK([DPP Exception])=TRUE,[Data Privacy Practices]<>"Yes"),FALSE,
IF(AND(ISBLANK([P/R Exception])=TRUE,[Preparation/Review]<>"Yes"),FALSE,
IF(AND(ISBLANK([ACK Exception])=TRUE,Acknowledgement<>"Yes"),FALSE,
IF(AND(ISBLANK([CS Exception])=TRUE,[Circulation Statistics]<>"Yes"),FALSE,
IF(AND(ISBLANK([P&S Exception])=TRUE,[Pilferage & Shrinkage]<>"Yes"),FALSE,
IF(AND(ISBLANK([SC Exception])=TRUE,[Single Copy Returns]<>"Yes"),FALSE,
IF(AND(ISBLANK([AA Exception])=TRUE,[Adjustments Accuracy]<>"Yes"),FALSE,
IF(AND(ISBLANK([PR Exception])=TRUE,[Payroll Review]<>"Yes"),FALSE,
IF(AND(ISBLANK([GL Exception])=TRUE,[General Ledger]<>"Yes"),FALSE,
IF(AND(ISBLANK([ELI Exception])=TRUE,[Expense Line Item]<>"Yes"),FALSE,
IF(AND(ISBLANK([RESP Exception])=TRUE,Responsibility<>"Yes"),FALSE,TRUE)))))))))))))
```

Comment: what you want to know? max limit of calculated field or how to extend it? max limit is 1024 characters

Answer (score 1):

Max limit CC field is 4000 bytes,

max string is 255 bytes,

max number of nested IF levels is 7 ..

I think there you run into an UI problem where the CC field does not display the contents.

Shorten your Formula... ISBLANK() itself returns a boolean so its not needed to compare with TRUEm same most likely applies to Yes/No fields.

But you do have an issue with the maximum of 7 nested IFs... split them into separate Calculated Columns

It looks like you can do without the IFS

Work towards ***something*** like

`= AND( 
  NOT( AND(ISBLANK([Resolved Exception]),Resolved<>"Yes") )
, NOT( AND(ISBLANK([Ethics Exception])  ,Ethics<>"Yes") )
, NOT( AND(ISBLANK([DPP Exception])     ,[Data Privacy Practices]<>"Yes") )
, NOT( AND(ISBLANK([P/R Exception])     ,[Preparation/Review]<>"Yes") )
, NOT( AND(ISBLANK([ACK Exception])     ,Acknowledgement<>"Yes") )
, NOT( AND(ISBLANK([CS Exception])      ,[Circulation Statistics]<>"Yes") )
, NOT( AND(ISBLANK([P&S Exception])     ,[Pilferage & Shrinkage]<>"Yes") )
, NOT( AND(ISBLANK([SC Exception])      ,[Single Copy Returns]<>"Yes") )
, NOT( AND(ISBLANK([AA Exception])      ,[Adjustments Accuracy]<>"Yes") )
, NOT( AND(ISBLANK([PR Exception])      ,[Payroll Review]<>"Yes") )
, NOT( AND(ISBLANK([GL Exception])      ,[General Ledger]<>"Yes") )
, NOT( AND(ISBLANK([ELI Exception])     ,[Expense Line Item]<>"Yes") )
, NOT( AND(ISBLANK([RESP Exception])    ,Responsibility<>"Yes") )
)`

I tripled checked the column names without any issues and the formula below is 950 out of the maximum 1014 characters so I really don't know why Sharepoint doesn't like it!

Is there a way to rewrite it? or shortened it?

```
= AND(NOT(AND(ISBLANK([Resolved Exception]),Resolved<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([Ethics Exception]),Ethics<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([DPP Exception]),[Data Privacy Practices]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([P/R Exception]),[Preparation/Review]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([ACK Exception]),Acknowledgement<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([CS Exception]),[Circulation Statistics]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([UV Exception]),[Unusual Variances]<>"Yes")),
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([P&S Exception]),[Pilferage & Shrinkage]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([SC Exception]),[Single Copy Returns]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([AA Exception]),[Adjustments Accuracy]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([PR Exception]),[Payroll Review]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([GL Exception]),[General Ledger]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([RESP Exception]),Responsibility<>"Yes")))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([UV Exception]),[Unusual Variances]<>"Yes"))
, NOT(AND(ISBLANK([ELI Exception]),[Expense Line Item]<>"Yes"))
)
```

Comment: Can you give an example how to split them into a separate calculated columns? The goal of the validation above is form cannot be submitted or will show a message if they choose one of the dropdowns A to <> Yes then leave the related textbox A to empty. I have many of this combination.

Comment: Brilliant, it is working but I have two questions, the = at the end of the formula is just a typo, correct? and secondly, Sharepoint is adding this at the end NOT(AND(ISBLANK(#NAME?)))) when I come back to edit the formula, any idea? I already double checked all the columns...

Comment: Yes, = is a type. #NAME? means SharePoint could not match the Column name. Start with one, then ADD them one by one and you will find the problem one.